# How to handle circular dependencies in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have the below code in my application

```
const citySchema = new Schema({
cityName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  citizen:[{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Citizen",
  }],
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("City", citySchema);


const citizenSchema = new Schema({
  citizenName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  city:{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "City",
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Citizen", citizenSchema);

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
      // req.body.cityName
      // req.body.citizenName
})
```

In my POST request , I receive both city name(new city) and citizen name(new citizen) that are not present . But I want both these schemas to be updated properly .

- City should contain Citizen references
- Citizen should contain City reference

How can I do that ? Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing that, I think you'll be much better to apply referencing via pre-hook middleware in your data model.

The code should be like this:

```js
const citySchema = new Schema({
cityName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  citizen:[{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Citizen",
  }],
});

// Query middleware to populate the 'citizen' attribute every time the 'find' function is called.
citySchema.pre(/^find/, function (next) {
  this.populate('citizen');
  next();
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("City", citySchema);

const citizenSchema = new Schema({
  citizenName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  city:{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "City",
  },
});

citizenSchema.pre(/^find/, function (next) {
  this.populate('city');
  next();
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Citizen", citizenSchema);
```

If you want to select just the ID and not the 'full data', you could do it like this for example:

```js
citizenSchema.pre(/^find/, function (next) {
  this.populate({
    path: 'city',
    select: '_id',
  });
  next();
});
```

Explanation:

- By doing this, every time you call Mongoose's functions like `findByIdAndUpdate`, `find`, `findOne`, the referenced data will appear in the `city` and `citizen` attribute. This is actually more efficient rather than updating each time there is a new data.
- The `populate` method is used to populate the attributes with data from another data model.
- The object that I inserted into the `populate` method is used to get the 'name' of the model (in the `path`), and to select what kind of data to take from the referenced model. In this case, I only want to take the `_id` attribute.